# computing future investment value in python error

Tags: python, function

So I am trying to solve this problem; The image contains some sample output.

[image: Problem to solve]

This is the code I have so far and I'm not sure where I am going wrong. Problem is it is not displaying the correct figures in the sample run.

```
investmentAmount=0
intr=0

   monthlyInterestRate=0

def futureInvestmentValue(investmentAmount, monthlyInterestRate, years):

    futureInvestmentValue=investmentAmount*(1+monthlyInterestRate)**years
    return futureInvestmentValue

def main():

  investmentAmount=int(input("The amount invested: "))
  intr=int(input("Annual interest rate: "))
  monthlyInterestRate=intr/1200

  print("Years Future Value")
     for yrs in range(1,31):

    FIV=futureInvestmentValue(investmentAmount,monthlyInterestRate,yrs)
      print(yrs, format(FIV, ".2f"))
 main()
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code ?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include some input/output/expected output examples? Tell us *why* and *how* it's not working and we can help you fix it.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I have edited the post

Comment: Are your equations correct?

Comment: You are mixing monthly and yearly interest rates. Your `futureInvestmentValue` should calculate the value per month and not per year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing months and year. In your code, you are actually calculating increments in months despite having named the variable `years`.  And you probably want to convert the interest rate to a `float` rather than an `int` to allow a wider range.

Here is the corrected code (I did not change the formula):

```
def future_investment_value(investment_amount, monthly_interest_rate, months):
    return investment_amount * (1 + monthly_interest_rate)**months

def main():
    investment_amount = int(input("The amount invested: "))
    yearly_interest_rate = float(input("Annual interest rate: "))
    monthly_interest_rate = yearly_interest_rate / 1200

    print("Months future value")
    for months in range(1, 30*12 + 1):
        fut_val = future_investment_value(
            investment_amount, monthly_interest_rate, months)

        if months % 12 == 0:
            print('{:3d} months | {:5.1f} years ==> {:15.2f}'.format(
                months, months / 12, fut_val))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see in the output, at 60 months (5 years), the output is what you expected:

```
The amount invested: 10000
Annual interest rate: 5
Months future value
 12 months |   1.0 years ==>        10511.62
 24 months |   2.0 years ==>        11049.41
 36 months |   3.0 years ==>        11614.72
 48 months |   4.0 years ==>        12208.95
 60 months |   5.0 years ==>        12833.59
 72 months |   6.0 years ==>        13490.18
...
336 months |  28.0 years ==>        40434.22
348 months |  29.0 years ==>        42502.91
360 months |  30.0 years ==>        44677.44
```